# Pexpect and GRUB - Why is Pexpect showing me a blank GRUB menu?

Tags: boot, pexpect, grub

I am attempting to script a reboot of a system and I have several GRUB entries.  Pexpect doesn't seem to "see" the menu items.

Here is a code snippet:

```
def get_menu_selections(xtn):
    print "Waiting for GNU GRUB to show"
    xtn.expect_exact("GNU GRUB", timeout=480)
    time.sleep(3)
    xtn.expect_exact('Use the ^ and v keys')
    print xtn.before
    print xtn.after

def main():
    connection = pexpect.spawn('ssh -l user -p2288 1.2.3.4')
    # reboot box
    get_menu_selections(connection)

main()
```

To explain why my snippet is like it is: Once "GNU GRUB" is on the screen, then my timeout stops, which means the wait for the system to reboot is over.  At that point, I am guessing that GRUB draws the box, then fills it in, so I'm sleeping 3 seconds to wait for the content of the GRUB menu to be drawn on the screen.  After I wait, then I was going to match on "Use the ^ and v keys" as my match so I can get a before and after.

This is what my GRUB looks like:

```
                  GNU GRUB  version 1.98+20100804-14+squeeze1

 +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 |Base OS                                                                   |
 |Base OS -> ttyS0                                                          |
 |Base OS (recovery mode)                                                   |
 |Base OS -> ttyS0 (recovery mode)                                          |
 |System Rescue                                                             |
 |System Rescue -> ttyS0                                                    |
 |                                                                          |
 +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+

  Use the ^ and v keys to select which entry is highlighted.
  Press enter to boot the selected OS, 'e' to edit the commands
  before booting or 'c' for a command-line.

  The highlighted entry will be executed automatically in 0s.
```

Instead of seeing the menu items, I'm only seeing the drawn outline and the text at the bottom.  This is what my code prints to the screen:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+     
|                                                                          |
|                                                                          |
|                                                                          |
|                                                                          |
|                                                                          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Use the ^ and v keys
```

I'd like to get the menu options into a buffer ("before", "match", or "after") so that I can take inventory.  Any idea how to grab the menu items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that GRUB first prints the `Use the ^ and v keys` messages before printing the menu entries. So try like this:

```
def get_menu_selections(xtn):
    print "Waiting for GNU GRUB to show"
    xtn.expect_exact("GNU GRUB", timeout=480)
    time.sleep(3)
    xtn.expect_exact('Use the ^ and v keys')
    time.sleep(3)
    xtn.expect_exact('System Rescue -> ttyS0')
    print xtn.before
    print xtn.after
```

Comment: I had thought this same thing and finally gotten around to testing it.  I did exactly what you suggested and can see the entire menu.  Thanks for the help!